How to upload base64 using an axios request
For all of the convert to base 64 functions I have found on stack overflow it requires using a promise. So i create a function that generates a new promise and I await on it for the response then return that. I use this function for all the files I am converting to base64 however for some reason when I get to my backend with the request it still says its a object.promise so I am assuming the await is not working correctly.
                getBase64 : async (file) => {
                let data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
                    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
                })
                return data
            },
            submitHistoricalPreprint() {
                
                if (this.$refs['AddHistoricalPreprintForm'].validate()) {

                    let form = new FormData()

                    this.historicalPreprintDocs.forEach((round, index) => {

                        form.append(`data[${index}].ppid`, this.selectPPID.PPID)

                        form.append(`data[${index}].round`, round.round)

                        if (round.preprint) {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].preprint.fileName`, round.preprint.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].preprint.content`, this.getBase64(round.preprint))
                        } else {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].preprint`, null)
                        }

                        round.supportingDocumentation ? round.supportingDocumentation.forEach((file, index2) => {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].supportingDocumentation[${index2}].fileName`, file.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].supportingDocumentation[${index2}].content`, this.getBase64(file))
                        }) : form.append(`data[${index}].supportingDocumentation`, null)

                        if (round.oactQuestions) {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].oactQuestions.fileName`, round.oactQuestions.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].oactQuestions.content`, this.getBase64(round.oactQuestions))
                        } else {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].oactQuestions`, null)
                        }

                        round.cmcsResponses ? round.cmcsResponses.forEach((file,index2) => {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].cmcsResponses[${index2}].fileName`, file.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].cmcsResponses[${index2}].content`, this.getBase64(file))

                        }) : form.append(`data[${index}].cmcsResponses`, null)

                        if (round.stateResponses) {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].stateResponses.fileName`, round.stateResponses.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].stateResponses.content`, this.getBase64(round.stateResponses))
                        } else {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].stateResponses`, null)
                        }

                        if (round.approvalLetter) {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].approvalLetter.fileName`, round.approvalLetter.name)
                            form.append(`data[${index}].approvalLetter.content`, this.getBase64(round.approvalLetter))
                        } else {
                            form.append(`data[${index}].approvalLetter`, null)
                        }
                    })

                    axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: window.location.origin + '/Preprint/UploadHistoricalReview',
                        data: form,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                            "RequestVerificationToken": document.forms[0].querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
                        }
                    }).then(response => {
                        this.historicalPreprintDocs = [{
                            "round": 1,
                            "preprint": null,
                            "supportingDocumentation": [],
                            "oactQuestions": null,
                            "cmcsResponses": [],
                            "stateResponses": null,
                            "approvalLetter": null,
                        }]
                        this.$refs['AddHistoricalPreprintForm'].reset();

                    }).catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status == 401 || error.response.status == 402 || error.response.status == 403) {
                            window.location.href = error.response.headers.expiredtokenredirecturi
                        }
                        console.log(error.response.data.error);
                    });
                }
            },


atob() converts to base64 and doesn't require a promise.

this.getBase64(...) returns a Promise because it is an async function. As soon as one function that is called in the process of generating the result involves the usage of a Promise (or any other kind of asynchronous handling), then that result can only be retrieved in an asynchronous way.

Using an asynchronous approach for this is fine, you just need to ensure that you handle your getBase64 function call asynchronously as well. Doing a form.append with the return value of getBase64 will append a promise, rather than the encoded value, so you need to await this call or use a .then. Example using async/await:
async submitHistoricalPreprint() {
    ...
    try {
        await Promise.all(this.historicalPreprintDocs.map(async (round, index) => {
            ...
            form.append(..., await this.getBase64(...));

            round.supportingDocumentation ? await Promise.all(round.supportingDocumentation.map(async (file, index2) => ...)) : ...;
            ...
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // handle file encoding failures
    }
    ...
}

Note: It's important that you use a Promise.all with a .map and an async callback (or a function that returns a promise) instead of the original .forEach so that you can properly handle any promise rejections. Additionally, doing the Promise.all with the .map allows for I/O concurrency, whereas a regular for...of loop with awaits would force them to be handled sequentially

I have a couple forEach loops that I will have await in. Do I need to tag on async () in them?

@Qiuzman if you mean you have more loops similar to the this.historicalPreprintDocs.forEach(... that also need to invoke getBase64, then yes those should also be use the approach of Promise.all + .map + async callback

No I mean inside that loop do you see the additional forEach loops I use? Do they require promise.all as well and adding async such as forEach(async(file, index2))

@Qiuzman ah I had missed those - yes, they need to use the same structure as well. Please refer to the note in my edited answer, it's important that you don't attempt to use forEach (instead swap it out with .map) as this will not expose the promises from your function calls and can result in unhandled promise rejection errors

I edited the example in my answer to include a sample of one of those nested loops. Since you have multiple nested loops, it may be better (from an I/O concurrency standpoint) to build an array of promises and do an await Promise.all(<array>) at the end of your top-level loop instead of individually awaiting each group of data.

So I have made your changes which I actually had tried earlier. However it returns an error related to the form : [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AddHistoricalPreprintForm')"

@Qiuzman sorry, I'm not familiar with Vue, I can't really answer that part. It seems you'll have to find a way to get the this.$refs to play nicely with the async logic. If you include the full stack trace of the error I can see if anything jumps out at me

So I was able to get it to work. My only question is does await.Promise.all() keep the code from going to the next line? For instance if after await.Promise.all() I have a axios request using that form data. Will the await ensure the code will not move to the next line until that promise.all returns a result? I am use to async/await in c# but sometimes find promises to act different.

@Qiuzman glad to hear it, and yes await causes the flow of execution in that async function to pause until the awaited task completes

Okay perfect. So similar to c#.

@Qiuzman In fact, because await waits for each task to complete is why in the note on my post I was suggesting instead adding all of the promises to an array and awaiting them in one combined Promise.all at the end. You will get more I/O concurrency by launching all of the tasks at once, rather than waiting for groups of them to finish sequentially. Though if the base64 encoding computation on the CPU is bottlenecking anyway then you may not see much of a difference

Just clarifying, in my previous comment I said I mentioned that optimization "in the note on my post" but that was incorrect/misleading - I mentioned it in an earlier comment
